# Capturing logcat on android x86

Tags: android, keyboard-shortcuts, x86, logcat

iam running android 2.2 (froyo) on a x-86 based PC. How can I capture a logcat on the terminal console and save it to any specific location within the android, say notepad ? Whats is the keyboard command for it ?

What are the other generic keyboard shortcuts for android x-86?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
adb logcat > logcat.txt
```

If you have an emulator and a device and you want to extract the logcat from the device, then:

```
adb -d logcat > logcat.txt
```

Type adb help for a list of the commands.

Comment: it didn't work, the logcat on Android x-86 terminal screen just goes on and on and stops by itself

Comment: by x-86 you mean a standard PC, right? Does "adb logcat" work? The "> logcat.txt" simply dumps the result to a new file created as "logcat.txt". If adb logcat works and the ">" part doesn't, google on how to dump a shell result to a file on your system. In Unix and Windows XP the "greater than" symbol works.

Comment: The '-d' must be placed after 'logcat', like so:  "adb logcat -d"

Comment: @dapper yes x-86 means standered PC. no need to write adb their simply  logcat cmd works and if you want to save the logcat into some space into memory then it must be in /data/.

Answer (score 0):

adb tool is not present for android x86

Comment: That depends on the actual build. Most android x86 builds I used have ADB present.

Comment: @ZoltanF but while using android x-86 standered PC there is no need to write adb certain shell cmd directly works